# Per test mocha results

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a folder with many mocha tests.

```
test/
├── api1.test.js
└── api2.test.js
```

etc…

What I would like to do is run all of the tests at once but keep track of the results per file so I know that api1.test passed:1 and failed:1 while api2.test.js passed:2 and failed:3. The tests are all integration tests and i want to store each api's test results in a database so I can keep track of the "health" of each api.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use mochawesome. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome